# How can I return a value from a thread in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

If I have the following code :

```
threads = []
(1..5).each do |i|
  threads << Thread.new { `process x#{i}.bin` } 
end
threads.each do |t|
  t.join
  # i'd like to get the output of the process command now.
end
```

What do I have to do to get the output of the process command? How could I create a custom thread so that I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The script

```
threads = []
(1..5).each do |i|
  threads << Thread.new { Thread.current[:output] = `echo Hi from thread ##{i}` }
end
threads.each do |t|
  t.join
  puts t[:output]
end
```

illustrates how to accomplish what you need. It has the benefit of keeping the output with the thread that generated it, so you can join and get the output of each thread at any time. When run, the script prints

```
Hi from thread #1
Hi from thread #2
Hi from thread #3
Hi from thread #4
Hi from thread #5
```

Comment: Vinay, maybe you can have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383470/why-is-this-running-like-it-isnt-threaded

Comment: Far nicer to simply return the output from the thread and use `puts t.value`

Comment: why threads do not interleave? Nothing like `Hi Hi Hi from thread #1 from...`

Comment: @Serge perhaps because of the GIL.

Comment: @Serge the output doesn't interleave because the printing itself is done serially. Note that the threads themselves don't print anything, all output is done in the loop at the end.

Answer (score 41):

I  found it simpler to use collect to collect the Threads into a list, and use thread.value to join and return the value from the thread - this trims it down to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
threads = (1..5).collect do |i|
  Thread.new { `echo Hi from thread ##{i}` }
end
threads.each do |t|
  puts t.value
end
```

When run, this produces:

```
Hi from thread #1
Hi from thread #2
Hi from thread #3
Hi from thread #4
Hi from thread #5
```

Comment: The one downside of this version relative to using `Thread.current[:output]` is that there is no way to have a timeout using `value`.

Answer (score 23):

This is a simple, and interesting way to use [Thread#value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-value):

```
a, b, c = [
  Thread.new { "something" },
  Thread.new { "something else" },
  Thread.new { "what?" }
].map(&:value)

a # => "something"
b # => "something else"
c # => "what?"
```

Comment: There is no need to call `join` because `value` does that internally.

Comment: Love this. Also, if one of your threads returns multiple values, you can still assign them by nesting assignments in parentheses e.g. `a, (b, c), d = `

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Queue.html) class. Each thread should put its result in the queue, and the main thread should fetch it from there. Notice that using that approach, results my be in a order different from thread creation order in the queue.

Comment: The Queue class is useful, but not necessary for the original poster's scenario, where there is no thread contention over a single value or collection of values. Therefore, thread locals suffice in this case.

Comment: Link is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Thread#value`:

```
threads = (1..5).collect do |i|
  Thread.new { `echo x#{i}.bin` }
end
threads.each do |t|
  puts t.value
end
```